How to apply a specific class in Twig based on the classes of an element?
I'm working on a Drupal website and trying to apply specific classes in Twig files based on the existing classes of an HTML element. Specifically, I want to apply the 'Card-label' class to the title of a card element that has the class 'views-field views-field-title'. Despite several attempts, I have been unable to achieve the desired result.
Here is an excerpt from my Twig file:
<div class="Cardlist">
    {% if title %}
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
    {% for row in rows %}
        {%
            set row_classes = [
                default_row_class ? 'views-row',
            ]
        %}
        <div class="Card">
            <div{{row.attributes.addClass(row_classes)}}>
                {{ row.content }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

I have attempted to add the 'Card-label' class using conditions in Twig to ensure it is only applied to the element with the class 'views-field views-field-title'. My attempt looked something like this:
{% if 'views-field views-field-title' in row.content['#row'].attributes.class %}
    <div class="Card-label">
        {{ title }}
    </div>
{% else %}
    {{ title }}
{% endif %}

Here is an example of the current HTML element:
<div class="views-field views-field-title">
    <span class="field-content">My Title</span>
</div>

And here is how I want the HTML element to look after applying the Twig classes:
<div class="Card">
    <div class="Card-label">
        <h3>My Title</h3>
    </div>
</div>

Drupal version: 10

If row.content['#row'].attributes.class is indeed an actual array then you would need to change your if- statement to the following:
{% if 'views-field' in row.content['#row'].attributes.class and 'views-field-title' in row.content['#row'].attributes.class %}
    Both "views-field" and "views-field-title" are inside the array
{% endif %} 

